# Reactive form trigger on value changes for a group of text field

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have 10 input textbox in a reactive form.
I want to trigger the value changes method for 6 input textbox.

I can trigger the form changes like

```
 this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
      // code here
  });
```

I can also trigger for the specific field changes like

```
this.myFormget('filedName').valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
          // code here
      });
```

But I can not trigger for the group of text filed on changes like Jquery class change.
Need your help

Comment: Hello. You can wrap 6 of them in a different FormGroup. If you can share your html file it would be more explanatory. Also, you are subscribing for the changes, you are not triggering them.

Comment: Thanks, I already created formgroup and on change working fine. But It will be look there are 6 text field in a same class html attribute and on change that class we can trigger a method in Jquery.

I want this types of feature for the reactive form.

Answer (score 0):

```
let fieldList: Map<string, boolean> = new Map<string, boolean>();
  fieldList.set('name', false);
  fieldList.set('id', false);
  let count = 0;
  Object.keys(this.Form.controls).forEach(key => {
    if (fieldList.has(key) && !fieldList.get(key) && this.Form.controls[key].dirty) {
      if (count > 5) {
        trigggerMethode()
      }
      else {
        count++;
        fieldList.set(key, true);
      }        
    }
  });
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.